# Where can I download qmlscene for Ubuntu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml, qtquick2

```
MMMMMM@unbuntu:~/QT/test4Qml$ qmlscene main.qml
```

> qmlscene: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmlscene': No such file or directory

My Qt Development Environment does not have `qmlscene`. I googled it, and I only found *.deb. How should I do it?

Comment: Make sure your version of Qt is 4.7 or above, QML is a part of QtQuick which was only introduced in 4.7.

Comment: The helpers can easily be built yourself after installing the qt-binaries. Just also install the sources and run an install of the desired package by ```qmake && make && make install```

Comment: aha.I had solved it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Qt is not installed by default in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4`. That directory is the default path when linux detects a dependency which requires Qt.

Where did you installed Qt? How did you installed it? Did you set the `PATH` environment variable to where Qt binaries are installed?

Usually, you have to follow the next steps:

- 1.- Install the the [basic requirements](http://www.qt.io/download/) for building Qt applications.
- 2.- [Download](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) Qt. I recommend Qt 5 using an offline installer. Otherwise, you'd need to compile from the source. [Here](http://download.qt.io/archive/qt/) you have a list of older versions of Qt.
- 3.- Set the environment variable `PATH` to the directory where you Qt `bin` directory is installed.

Comment: Thank for your answer! and I resolve my problem beacause of your answer.  finally I had found qmlscene in default installed path (/home/MMMMMM/Qt/5.4/gcc_64). ,I had echo $PATH,do not found path list on my question.one more question,How do I set the PATH environment variable to where Qt binaries are installed?

Comment: LOL,Just now I use qmlscene tool by clicking tool/external/qtquick/qmlscene from menu bar. But I still want to know how to run qmlscene on console.

Comment: @No.6 Well, you can run `qmlscene` writing the absolute path. In your case, `/home/MMMMMM/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/qmlscene`. Anyway, the best option is [setting the PATH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) in your shell profile file. I.e: if you are using `bash` as login shell, edit the file `~/.bashrc` and add a line like `export PATH=/home/MMMMMM/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH`. After that, close and open again the terminal, or just run `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thank for your **reply** again,and I solve my question correctly.

Comment: Great! :) Thanks to you.

Comment: @No.6 Did you set the answer as unaccepted? Do you need anything else to solve the problem?

Comment: sorry,maybe I did it accidently.I hope I dont affect your insparation to answer newer

Comment: @No.6 Of course not :) I thought you needed more help. Take care!

Comment: hey～～～～．can you see my new question? I encounted a new question.and I have spended  a lot time

Comment: @No.6 I've just seen that your question was already answered. Is the answer OK for you? Problem solved?

Comment: oh!yes!because of  shit GFW.I cant reply replier quickly.thankyou very much. l love this web